# Spring Rest Docs with JUnit 5 and Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, junit5, spring-restdocs

I am unable to get a Spring Rest Docs test with JUnit 5 and Webflux working.

I have a working integration test with `@WebFluxTest` like this:

```
@WebFluxTest(SomeController.class)
class SomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient testClient;
    @MockBean
    private SomeService service;

    @Test
    void testGetAllEndpoint() {

        when(service.getAll())
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Machine(1,"Machine 1", "192.168.1.5", 9060)));

        testClient.get().uri("/api/machines")
                  .exchange()
                  .expectStatus().isOk()
                  .expectBodyList(Machine.class)
                  .hasSize(1);
    }
}
```

I now want to write a documentation test. According to the docs, something like this should work:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})
class SomeControllerDocumentation {

    private WebTestClient testClient;
    @MockBean
    private SomeService service;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
                      RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        this.testClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(webApplicationContext)
                                       .configureClient()
                                       .filter(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                                       .build();
    }

    @Test
    void testGetAllEndpoint() {

        when(service.getMachines())
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Machine(1, "Machine 1", "192.168.1.5", 9060)));

        testClient.get().uri("/api/machines")
                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                          .exchange().expectStatus().isOk()
                          .expectBody().consumeWith(document("machines-list"));
    }
}
```

I however get:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: 
Failed to resolve parameter [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext] 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I am also wondering if `@SpringBootTest` is needed as annotation or if `@WebFluxTest(SomeController.class)` is also supposed to work.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3 with `spring-restdocs-webtestclient` as dependency.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/582 -> The documentation was indeed wrong. Will be fixed in 2.0.4 of Spring Restdocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injecting `WebApplicationContext` use this:

```java
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        client = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
            .configureClient()
            .filter(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answer of Gilad Peleg, you can just change the type in the method argument from `WebApplicationContext` to `ApplicationContext`.

Note also that instead of `@SpringBootTest`, you can use `@WebFluxTest(SomeController.class)`

Comment: I find this solution to be more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-docs-web-test-client):

> @AutoConfigureRestDocs can also be used with WebTestClient. You can
> inject it by using @Autowired and use it in your tests as you normally
> would when using @WebFluxTest and Spring REST Docs, as shown in the
> following example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.AutoConfigureRestDocs;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

import static org.springframework.restdocs.webtestclient.WebTestClientRestDocumentation.document;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
public class UsersDocumentationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

}
```